# SQL:How to extract the correct date value from a file after bulk insert into a table and get total of amounts?

Tags: sql, bulkinsert, sql-server-2016

I did a bulk insert into a table.

All the data is inserted into `Data` column

I have the something like that inside of a data column:

```
1451678889   1451678889   2017092   2017092       500,000.00       10,000.00
1451678889   1451678889   2017091   2017091       500,000.00       10,000.00
1451678889   1451678889   2017092   2017092       500,000.00       10,000.00
```

Now, I need to get a date from `2017092` in the `yyyy-mm-dd` format:
where 2017 - year and 92 is a number of the day in this year.

Also, I will need to get totals grouped by date.

When executing this query:

```
select substring([data],34,15) from Staging_Table where ltrim(rtrim(substring([Data],42,5))) = '92'
```

I get the correct string `2017092`

When trying to do that to test the logic:

```
select dateadd(day, ltrim(rtrim(right('2017092',3))) - 1, DATEFROMPARTS(left('2017092',4) + 0, 1 ,1))
```

I get this: `2017-04-02` , which is the correct date for year 2017 and day 92

Now, when substituting '2017092' with the actual data from the table:

```
select dateadd(day,ltrim(rtrim(right(substring('1451678889   1451678889   2017092   2017092',34,15),3))) - 1, DATEFROMPARTS(left(substring('1451678889   1451678889   2017092   2017092',34,15),4) + 0, 1,1))
```

or querying the actual table:

```
select dateadd(day,right(ltrim(rtrim(substring([Data],34,15))),3) - 1, DATEFROMPARTS(left(substring([Data],34,15),4) + 0, 1, 1)) from Staging_Table
where ltrim(rtrim(substring([Data],42,5))) = '92'
```

I'm getting some strange result: `0002-04-02` - with the wrong year.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to fix your import so the data goes into different columns.

Answer (score 1):

Adjusting the substring values to:

```
select 
    Days = substring('1451678889   1451678889   2017092   2017092',41,3)
  , Year = substring('1451678889   1451678889   2017092   2017092',37,4)
  , Date = dateadd(day,substring('1451678889   1451678889   2017092   2017092',41,3) - 1
    , datefromparts(substring('1451678889   1451678889   2017092   2017092',37,4)+0, 1,1)
  )
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/MED20206

returns:

```
+------+------+---------------------+
| Days | Year |        Date         |
+------+------+---------------------+
|  092 | 2017 | 2017-04-02 00:00:00 |
+------+------+---------------------+
```

---

To make it a little more flexible, you can use `patindex()` to identify the likely position of the substring you want:

```
create table t (data varchar(256));
insert into t values 
 ('1451678889   1451678889   2017092   2017092       500,000.00       10,000.00')
,('1451678889   1451678889   2017091   2017091       500,000.00       10,000.00')
,('1451678889   1451678889   2017092   2017092       500,000.00       10,000.00');

/* --------------- */

select 
    Days = substring(data,patindex('% [1-2][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] %',data)+5,3)
  , Year = substring(data,patindex('% [1-2][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] %',data)+1,4)
  , Date = dateadd(day,substring(data,patindex('% [1-2][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] %',data)+5,3) - 1
    , datefromparts(substring(data,patindex('% [1-2][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] %',data)+1,4)+0, 1,1)
  )
from t
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/JWJVE60941

returns:

```
+------+------+---------------------+
| Days | Year |        Date         |
+------+------+---------------------+
|  092 | 2017 | 2017-04-02 00:00:00 |
|  091 | 2017 | 2017-04-01 00:00:00 |
|  092 | 2017 | 2017-04-02 00:00:00 |
+------+------+---------------------+
```

And to clean up the code a little we can throw the pattern into a variable:

```
declare @pattern varchar(64) = '% [1-2][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] %';

select 
    Days = substring(data,patindex(@pattern,data)+5,3)
  , Year = substring(data,patindex(@pattern,data)+1,4)
  , Date = dateadd(day,substring(data,patindex(@pattern,data)+5,3) - 1
    , datefromparts(substring(data,patindex(@pattern,data)+1,4)+0, 1,1)
  )
from t
```